# From multiple excel files and multiple sheets to a single excel file but with different excel sheets in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python. I am to sorry if my description will not be so clear. 
There are multiple excel files which names are not unique and with a lot of worksheets (more than 250). I do not want to input excel file names, because its amount and names are being changed often. But number of sheet and counts are same. I tried several codes but could not get conclusion. Here what I tried, could you please let me know what is missing ?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


files = os.listdir(r'path')
os.chdir(r'path')
df = pd.DataFrame()



# I used one of the file to extract list of sheet names

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Python\db\A.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.sheetnames



writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in sheet_names:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, index=False)
    for f in files:
        data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=i)
        df = df.append(data)
writer.save()
```